# Using sed to replace beginning of line when match found

Tags: regex, sed

I have a Java file. I want to comment any line of code that contains the match:

```
 myvar
```

I think sed should help me out here

```
 sed 's/myVar/not_sure_what_to_put_here/g' MyFile.java
```

I don't know what to put in:

```
not_sure_what_to_put_here
```

as in this case, I don't want to replace myVar but the I want to insert

```
//
```

to the beginning of any line myVar occurs on.

Any tips

Comment: so far both answers below will do the job for you. I would like to remind you that, you have to refine your pattern "myvar" to avoid unexpected replacement to happen. e.g. all lines containing "myVariable or myVarList or myVarMap or Object obj=new Object; //myVar in comment" will be commented out.

Comment: @Kent good point. It should be as tight as possible.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Capture the whole line that contains `myvar`:

```
$ sed 's/\(^.*myvar.*$\)/\/\/\1/' file

$ cat hw.java
class hw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
        myvar=1
    }
}

$ sed 's/\(^.*myvar.*$\)/\/\/\1/' hw.java
class hw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
//        myvar=1
    }
}
```

Use the `-i` option to save the changes in the file `sed -i 's/\(^.*myvar.*$\)/\/\/\1/' file`.

Explanation:

```
(      # Start a capture group
^      # Matches the start of the line 
.*     # Matches anything 
myvar  # Matches the literal word 
.*     # Matches anything
$      # Matches the end of the line
)      # End capture group
```

So this looks at the whole line and if `myvar` is found the results in stored in the first capture group, referred to a `\1`. So we replace the whole line `\1` with the whole line preceded by 2 forward slashes `//\1` of course the forwardslashes need escaping as not to confused `sed` so `\/\/\1` also note that brackets need escaping unless you use the extended regex option of `sed`.

Comment: this is looking good.  Q1 can you explain the logic of your answer? i.e. what do the /\(^.* etc do?

Comment: brilliant!  I just wanted to understand and not just get the thing done. Great answer.

Comment: In a separate regex, I want to detect the end of line and I am using `sed -i "s/cb $i$/cb $i $cb/" */callback_events`. But I am getting error of `Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.`. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Good answer but it would be easier to read if you use another separator instead of slash, e.g. hash: sed 's#\(^.*myvar.*$\)#//\1#' hw.java

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
sed -n '/myVar/{s|^|//|};p' MyFile.java
```

which means: when a line contains `myVar`, replace the beginning of the line with `//`.

Comment: I am on windwons, the | becomes ¦ and I get: '¦' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: ok, then you'll have to use escaped slashes: `sed -n '/myVar/{s/^/\/\//};p' MyFile.java`

Comment: Or put the script in a file if your (miserable wreck of an excuse for an) OS doesn't offer a way to quote a literal string. Maybe double quotes instead of single would work, though.

Answer (score 4):

I was researching the same topic and found this solution which is simpler in terms of the regex

`sed -e '/myvar/ s/^/\/\//' file`

This adds `//` to column 0 of the line with the matching pattern.

However, I was looking for a solution which will allow me to add a character before the first character of the line (not on column 0).