# Need to match two groups in Sed expression

Tags: regex, sed

This is similar to [Using sed to replace beginning of line when match found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137353/using-sed-to-replace-beginning-of-line-when-match-found) but a different question so hence this thread.

I wish to uncommented out commented out code. More specially, all cases where the variable myVar is commented out.

Example:

```
public class MyClass {
   ...
   ...
   //myVar.setAge(200);
   //myVar.setPlanet("mars");
}
```

to

```
public class MyClass {
   ...
   ...
   myVar.setAge(200);
   myVar.setPlanet("mars");
}
```

The regex:

```
^\\.*myVar.*$
```

Gets me everything I need.

The tricky part is getting the correct Sed. I try:

```
sed 's/(^\\)(.*myVar.*$)/\2/g' Build_DM_Digests_Batch.cls
```

On the following basis. Create two match groups. The first one is the commented out lines. And the second is the rest of line. Replace the entire line with just the second mateched group.

This gives error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 29: Unmatched ) or \)
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed 's/^\( *\)\/\/\(.*myVar.*$\)/\1\2/' file`

```
$ cat hw.java 
class hw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
//        myVar=1
        //myVar.setAge(200);
        //myVar.setPlanet("mars");
    }
}

$ sed 's/^\( *\)\/\/\(.*myVar.*$\)/\1\2/' hw.java
class hw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
        myVar=1
        myVar.setAge(200);
        myVar.setPlanet("mars");
    }
}
```

Use the `-i` option to save the changes in the file `sed -i 's/^\( *\)\/\/\(.*myVar.*$\)/\1/' file`:

Explanation:

```
^      # Matches the start of the line
\(     # Start first capture group  
 *     # Matches zero or more spaces
\)     # End first capture group
\/\/   # Matches two forward slashes (escaped)
\(     # Start second capture group 
.*     # Matches anything 
myVar  # Matches the literal word 
.*     # Matches anything
$      # Matches the end of the line
\)     # End second capture group
```

Here we capture the whitespace upto the `//` and then everything after if `myVar` on the line and replace with `\1\2`.

Your logic is almost there but a couple of things, firstly escaped all brackets and secondly you want `^( *)\/\/` not `^\\` that is two escaped forwardslashes with the whitespace captured not two backslashes at the start of the line:

If you don't want to escape brackets you need to use the extended regexp flag of `sed` which is `-r` for `GNU sed` on `OSX` it's `-E` so check with `sed --help`.

```
sed -r 's/^( *)\/\/(.*myVar.*$)/\1\2/' file
```

Note: when you are matching the whole line (from `^` to `$`) the `g` flag is redundant.

Comment: looking excellent. Can you tell me why we have to escape the brackets in sed but not grep?

Comment: `//` is not at the start of the line in the OP's example, so this will not work.

Comment: Use an alternate separator so you don't have to escape the slashes. Basically `s%//%%`

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
sed 's!^\([ \t]*\)//\(.*\<myVar\>\)!\1\2!' input
```

Answer (score 0):

[Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14138033/4341534) and explanation are valid. However, I would like to add a much cleaner equivalent expression. This expression relies on two changes

- Changing the separator to any character not included in the regexp, eg `|`, gets rid of the escape characters for `/`
- Specifying an extended regular expression (`-r`) gets rid of the escapes for parentheses `()`

This results in a readable command which is clearer in its intent and closer to what you would have expected to use.

```
sed -r 's|^( *)//(.*myVar.*$)|\1\2|' filename
```

Comment: Well, it's only the one change I guess. I initially missed the last iteration and didn't realize Chris already recommended using `-r`